# How do you mock a method in GroovyTestCase?

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, mocking

I've been trying to figure out stubbing and mocking through the groovy testing tutorial to no avail.  I'm trying to stub (or mock, I'm not quite sure on the terminology) this method, however I can't figure out how to actually get the syntax right.  I would appreciate some help.  I'm using groovy 2.4.5

```
public class foo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        method1();
    }

    public static void method1(){
    //do stuff
        Object baz = new Object();
        method2(baz);
    }
    public static void method2(Object baz){
        //do stuff
    }
}


class FooTest extends groovy.util.GroovyTestCase {
    void testMainLoop(){
        def stubMethod2 = new StubFor(foo);
        stubMethod2.ignore.method2
        stubMethod2.use {
            foo.method1();
        }
    }
}
```

This code throws the error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: method2 for class: groovy.mock.interceptor.Ignore
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.java:87)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296)
at fooTest.testMainLoop(fooTest.groovy:14)
```

Comment: The failing code that I'm using is similar to the code that I saw in the tutorial here: http://www.groovy-lang.org/testing.html#_mockfor_and_stubfor which is why I'm so confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather use:

```
stubMethod2.ignore('method2')
```

than:

```
stubMethod2.ignore.method2
```

Could you please clarify what you want to achieve?

BTW: I suggest to use [spock](https://github.com/spockframework/spock) instead of groovy built-in testing.